# find_by returning nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

I have the following find_by call in my controller, the issue is that when there isnt an id for the call its returning a nil class error

```
if current_user.admin?
  @schedules = Schedule.all
else
  @schedules = Schedule.find_by_team_id(current_user[:team_id])
end
```

if the id exist it all works fine, any ideas why i am getting this error?

Comment: You get this error because there is no id in hash :).
You should just check if id exists in hash with `current_user.has_key? :team_id`. Why didn't you use `current_user.team_id` ? I think It works

Comment: @tiktak that didnt seem to work, still gives me nil class error

Comment: You mean that when `:team_id` is a number not related to any `team` on your database or is `nil` you get error?

Comment: Hi Lucus, exactly if the id doesnt exist or is nil we get an error